# Vue.js saving data between redirects

Tags: vue.js

I'm building a vue.js application with a redirect to an external credit card payment page which then redirects back to my app. How do I keep my app data between these redirects? (quite a large amount of data otherwise I might have passed it in the URL params). What is the best practice to do that in Vue.js?

Comment: what kind of data you need to pass and save between requests?

Comment: When do you Redirect you are out of scope, maybe in session storage?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: @AndrewShmig user data and other transaction data (not payment details)

Comment: @HadarRosin, are you exiting from your application?
Please show some code, on how you want to do that.

Comment: Post a code example from what you are building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store something while the page is no longer loaded, you have to use the [Web Storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). You can use sessionStorage, localStorage or maybe something like IndexedDB. Simply restore the state from there whenever the application loads again.